# Multiple FolderScope's in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have a simple PowerShell script to create an email a report on our jounraling mailbox:

```
$smtpServer = "1.2.3.4"
$from = "madeup@emailaddress.com"
$emailaddress = "madeup@emailaddress.com"
$subject = "Journaling Mailbox Report"
$mailboxreport = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics Journaling_mailbox | select Date, Name, FolderPath, FolderType, ItemsInFolder | ConvertTo-HTML
$body = "$mailboxreport"
Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer $smtpServer -from $from -to $emailaddress -subject $subject -body $body -bodyasHTML
```

Now, the script works great, but I would like to specifiy a certain selection of from the journaling mailbox, as opposed to all folders. I can specify one folder using the -FolderScope parameter - is it possible to use this parameter with more than one folder, or do I have to do something a little more complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folder scope only takes a single folder name for scope.

You can filter out multiple folders at once using a filter with an alternation regex:

```
$mailboxreport = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics Journaling_mailbox |
 select Date, Name, FolderPath, FolderType, ItemsInFolder |
 Where {$_.FolderPath -match '/(Folder1|Folder2)/'} |
 ConvertTo-HTML
```

Comment: Just a quick and somewhat delayed shout to say thanks, that worked a treat!

Comment: Glad it worked for you!  Would you mind marking it answered so it doesn't keep showing up as an unanswered question?